# int array to IEnumerable<MyTestObj>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a MVC that posts an array of integers, and I want to convert that array of int's to `IEnumerable<MyTestObj>`. How is that done? It seems I can't use `myintArr.AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need something along the lines of the following (depending how you create the object):

```
myIntArr.Select(i => new MyTestObj(i));
// or...
myIntArr.Select(i => (MyTestObj)i);
// or...
myIntArr.Select(i => new MyTestObj { SomeProperty = i });
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing the point here, but doesn't an array support IEnumerable? In other words just use your array as it is (assuming you want an enumerable of int).

If you want an enumerable collection of some other object I think the other answers address that, but it's not clear (to me at least) what it is you are trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. I am assuming that you have something like this for an action:

`public ActionResult MyAction(int [] postedValues)`

If that's the case then `postedValues` would already be IEnumerable.  Not sure what problem you are having.  It this isn't what you were asking then look at wither Mehrdad's or Andreas's answers.